# How to deselect rest index with list in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a list of buttons in row , there are 4 items or buttons in list,
I have made a model class for creating data for each button, the list is model type.
all working fine, I want to highlight or select the button, on which I pressed and rest index button should be deselected.
I'm able to highlight the pressed button but unable to deselect the rest buttons.

code

```
//Button model class

class TopButtonModel{
   String buttonLable;
   bool isOnTp;
   TopButtonModel({this.buttonLable, this.isOnTp});
 }


//initializing list with these data

int myIndex=0;

List<TopButtonModel> buttons = [
   TopButtonModel(
     buttonLable: 'Skin',
     isOnTp: true
   ),
    TopButtonModel(
     buttonLable: 'Hair Style',
     isOnTp: false
   ),
    TopButtonModel(
     buttonLable: 'Makeup',
     isOnTp: false
   ),
    TopButtonModel(
     buttonLable: 'Handset & Feet',
     isOnTp: false
   ),
   
   
   ];


buttonsRow() {

 return Container(
   color: Colors.white,
   child: ListView.builder(
     // Rpadding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 9),
     scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
     itemCount: buttons.length,
     itemBuilder:(context, index) {
       // myIndex =in
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 9,top: 9),
        child: FlatButton(
          color: buttons[index].isOnTp?Colors.indigo:Colors.grey[200],
          onPressed: () {
            print(index);
            setState(() {
              myIndex =index;
              buttons[index].isOnTp =true;
            
               
            });

           //  if (buttons.any((item) => item.isOnTp)) {
            
           //       setState(() {
           //          buttons[index].isOnTp = !buttons[index].isOnTp;
           //       });
           //      }
          
           }, 
          child: Text(buttons[index].buttonLable,
          style: TextStyle(color: buttons[index].isOnTp?Colors.white:Colors.black),
          )),
      );
     }
   ),
 ) ;
      
}
```

wanna achieve this

[image]

and what is happening

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be as simple as this:

```
setState(() {
    buttons[myIndex].isOnTp = false;
    myIndex = index;
    buttons[index].isOnTp = true;
});
```

Here is a working code example: [Code Pen](https://codepen.io/umairem/pen/zYqQVxp)

Comment: check the link I posted